# Can anyone recommend a source control tutorial for a non-technical user based on TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Can anyone recommend a source control tutorial for a test engineer based on TortoiseSVN?  It needs to cover how to check stuff out in detail; the rest can be a bit sketchy if necessary.

Comment: somehow non-technical users have a hard time grasping source control. Somebody should really figure out how to explain it for the masses!

Comment: @Daren: heartily agreed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first couple chapters of the "Version Control with Subversion" book might be good. The [original version is available online](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), but even better [the folks at TortoiseSVN have tweaked their own version](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/index.html).

If the above one is too long, there's a [shorter visual tutorial by Sergio Lopes here](http://wiki.sergio-lopes.org/index.php?n=Rabble.TortoiseSVNTutorial).

Answer (score 1):

The TortoiseSVN help file is excellent.

Chapter 2 on Versioning Models and Subversion in Action is a great explanation of how version control works and how TortoiseSVN is implemented.

Chapter 4 Daily Use Guide should cover be all that your test engineer needs to understand.